# Show name if issue

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm organizing a spreadsheet for a game where I have the name, power, and class of all the member of my guild and I want to find the member with the highest power per class.

Example:

[image: example from my spreadsheet]

I want a formula that searches the highest value on the "power" column if the value on the "type" column is for example "Healer" and outputs the name of said member.

How can I do that?

Comment: I'm editing the spreadsheet in Google Docs as I don't own a version of Microsoft Excel at the moment. Is that an issue !?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What formulas have you already tried? Please note this is probably not the best site to ask for how formulas in general work, but if you already tried to learn yourself and got stuck on a concrete problem then that could be interesting. If you tried a specific formula that didn't work, can you edit your question to insert it, and to insert what exactly went wrong? That will make it easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(SORTN(SORT(A33:D; 3; 1; 4; 0); 9^9; 2; 3; 1);;1)
```

[image]

Comment: I think I express my issue wrong and I apologize. I want the result to be the name of the player on the same line where the max value is. Does that help ? I was looking into maybe using a VLOOKUP type of formula... Would that work ?

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gIZjaUG0fgtQiIU4XssyO5GJU5M86QEQHUy1md40XV4/edit?usp=sharing Does that help ?